# Apache custom errors

Tags: apache2, .htaccess

I'm having trouble with doing custom error messages in Apache.

I've read Apache documentation and basic syntax is quite clear and simple. Only problem I'm having is I don't know in what config file I should put them. It's also hard to understand older questions about same subject due different config system it was before.

My .htaccess (I don't know if this is needed, I do have full control of server)

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

if you need something else, please tell and I'll get them

Edit: I'm running on Ubuntu Server 14 LTS and Apache 2.4.7

Edit2:

- I've enabled rewrite module
- /etc/apache2/sites-available/default looks like:

  `<Directory /var/www/> 
      Options Indexed FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
  </Directory>`
- I tried [How To Create A Custom ErrorDocument Page In Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509802/how-to-create-a-custom-errordocument-page-in-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1) but it isn't working.
- I've restarted apache after every change
- My files are 404.html index.html and .htaccess and they are all at /var/www/html
- Tried [Enable use of .htaccess in apache2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445594/enable-use-of-htaccess-in-apache2?rq=1) still not working

Comment: Rewrite Engine on -> RewriteEngine on

Comment: @madneon fixed & restarted -> no change, so still not working

Answer (score 0):

like in [Apache Doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html):

> Custom error documents are configured using the ErrorDocument directive, which may be used in global, virtualhost, or directory context. **It may be used in .htaccess** files if AllowOverride is set to FileInfo.

So it should be okay in .htaccess Files.
Did it work for you?

Comment: My .htaccess file is above

Comment: I see a typo: "Enginge" should be "Engine".

Comment: @Jos Fixed that, still not working

Comment: Anything useful in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`?